# How to automate react native application in which clickable=false

Tags: selenium-webdriver, react-native, appium

I am trying to automate React native android application through Appium, I am trying to click on the button but it is `clicakble=false` so I am unable to do further script

Comment: is the unclickable in manual step as well?

Comment: No in manual it is clickable but when I m inspecting from UI Automator it shows clickable = false.

Comment: Please share the HTML or code

Answer (score 0):

Try to click using `JavascriptExecutor`

```
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Your Xpath"));
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

OR

```
            Point point = ad.findElement(filter).getLocation();
            int elementCenterX = point.getX() + 80;
            int elementCenterY = point.getY() + 100;
            System.out.println("value of x = "+elementCenterX+"   value of y = "+elementCenterY);
            ad.tap(2, elementCenterX , elementCenterY , 0);
            System.out.println("click on result");
```

Comment: Yes it is a class of selenium and it is core java code :)

Comment: Hi   JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
     Object element = null;
  executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element); this is not working..

Comment: Why are you passing null .. pass the webelement of button

Comment: yes, I have tried like this  JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;    executor.executeScript("android.view.ViewGroup[4].click()","button");
      Still, it shows error

Comment: java.util.List<WebElement>  a= driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.EditText"));
 
  a.get(0).sendKeys("ak");
  a.get(1).sendKeys("abcd");
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  
     JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
     executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", "button");  But I dont have any id of that react native button and button is clickable='false'

Comment: button is not a string. i have update the example in my answer

Comment: WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.ViewGroup[@index='2']/android.widget.Button[@index='2']"))  i have tried by this way but still it does not do any action

Comment: If that doesn't work then I have added a another code with click using co-ordinates ... just adjust the x and y as per your requirement.